# Issue with emails on SendGrid and Outlook after Outlook's update. Test emails match new version, but old Outlook distorts design

Tags: outlook, sendgrid

**Experiencing email issues on SendGrid and Outlook after Outlook's update. Test emails match new version design, but recipients with old Outlook see distorted emails, different from intended structure.
**
I am noticing an issue with my emails on SendGrid and outlook. Since outlook has updated to a new version, my test emails look exactly like the ones designed on the new version, however for anyone who has the old version of outlook the email is all messed up and looks nothing like what I designed structure wise.

I have brought this issue up with SendGrid, but they told me to contact Outlook directly.

So here is my problem: Initially before there was a new outlook update, SendGrid emails worked perfectly, I tested and sent out emails multiple times. Which means that with the old outlook it was still good once I updated my outlook to a new version, SendGrid emails on the new version still looked great as before, however everyone (including me) that opened the same email on the old outlook, had the email structure completely messed up.
How can I solve this issue?

Screenshots attached here as I was unable to upload the photos in the this box!
[Images LINK](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12De_O9tOoWVBpj_PTv8m4dxlRBqPjRnd?usp=sharing)